# how to make spark streaming asynchronously when read from Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have one Kafka partition, and one sparkStreaming application. One server with 10 cores. When the spark streaming get one message from Kafka, the subsequent process will take 5 seconds(this is my code). So I found sparkStreaming read Kafka message very slow, I'm guessing that when spark read out one message then it will wait until the message was processed, so the reading and processing are synchronized.
I was wondering can I make the spark reading asynchronously? So the reading from Kafka won't be dragged by the subsequent processing. Then the spark will very quickly consume data from Kafka. And then I can focus on the slow data process inside spark. btw, I'm using foreachRDD function.

Answer (score 0):

you can increase the number of partitions in kafka, it should improve the parallelism , also you can try with "Direct kafka receiver" which really improve the performance when your app is reading from kafka